# Rewrite domain url for php script with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

php or js script works correctly only on domain1.com

Can I fool them with .htaccess to think I use domain1.com while actually having domain2.com in url? That is having `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` return domain2.com

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

These instructions aren't quite working.

Comment: Why does "php or js script works correctly only on domain1.com"? The reason "why" it doesn't currently work may determine whether you can "fake it" as you are asking. "That is having `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` return domain2.com" - don't you mean "domain1.com"? Bear in mind that JS runs client-side, so only sees the URL in the address bar (ie. `domain2.com`).

Comment: Why does it work so, only 42 knows. I know usually it's smart to look for the exact problem, but in this case it seems like it's a fair chance to try doing exactly what I'm trying to do, and that's trying to fool php script into thinking I'm using other domain. It's just like using regular 301 redirect with .htacces, but without following the second url.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative that is not related to htaccess but you can create an index.php in your root of domain 2 and redirect it to domain1 like this:

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('Location: http://domain1.com'.$uri);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to move to new url. I need to phisically stay on old url, while having new one in adress bar.